# How can I make my loop start with zero instead of one?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone advise how to adjust this table to include a "heading" and have the table values start at 1 not 0. The values should add like this:

```
1  2  3  4  5  
2  4  6  8  10
3  6  9  12 15
4  8  12 16 20
5  10 15 20 25
```

Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Table</title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 27px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function createTable() {
                rn = window.prompt("Input number of rows");
                cn = window.prompt("Input number of columns");

                for (var r = 0; r < parseInt(rn, 10); r++) {
                    var x = document.getElementById("myTable").insertRow(r);
                    for (var c = 0; c < parseInt(cn, 10); c++) {
                        var y = x.insertCell(c);
                        y.innerHTML =  + r +  + c;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        <table id="myTable" border="1"></table>
        <form>
            
            <input type="button" onclick="createTable()" value="Create the table"/>
            
            
        </form>
        <h1>To create your own table, please click the create table button.</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "have the table values start at 1 not 0"? Just... literally do that? It's your code, you're starting loop counters at `0`, either add 1 where  needed, or start them at 1.

Comment: by using maths, I figure you want `y.innerHTML =  (r + 1 ) * (c + 1);` - as an aside: why are you using unary `+` to "coerce" `r` and `c` to be `Number`s ... since they are already `Number`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have 3 problems, all with simple solutions:

- You're missing a header row. Simply add one before the loop that creates the rest of the rows. You can use [`createTHead`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/createTHead) instead of `insertRow`. It doesn't come with `insertCell` though, so you do require to manually create and append the `<th>` elements.
- Your values start at 0 instead of 1. Why not simply `+1` the values? Or start at 1 instead of 0?
- Your math formula is wrong. Why not change it then?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Table</title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 27px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function createTable() {
                rn = window.prompt("Input number of rows");
                cn = window.prompt("Input number of columns");
                
                const table = document.getElementById("myTable"); // gonna use it several times
                table.innerHTML = ''; // Empty the table
                
                // Add the head and fill it with cells
                const head = table.createTHead();
                for (let i = 1; i <= cn; i++) {
                    const th = document.createElement('th');
                    th.innerText = i;
                    head.appendChild(th);
                }

                // Add all the rows and cells
                for (var r = 1; r <= parseInt(rn, 10); r++) {
                    var x = table.insertRow(); // no need for an index if it's just to append
                    for (var c = 1; c <= parseInt(cn, 10); c++) {
                        var y = x.insertCell(); // no need for an index if it's just to append
                        y.innerText =  r * c; // changed the formula
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        <table id="myTable" border="1"></table>
        <form>
            
            <input type="button" onclick="createTable()" value="Create the table"/>
            
            
        </form>
        <h1>To create your own table, please click the create table button.</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```